# TERADATA: Aggregate across multiple tables

Tags: sql, join, aggregate-functions, teradata

Consider the following query where aggregation happens across two tables: Sales and Promo and the aggregate values are again used in a calculation.

```
SELECT

  sales.article_id,
  avg((sales.euro_value - ZEROIFNULL(promo.euro_value)) / NULLIFZERO(sales.qty - ZEROIFNULL(promo.qty)))

FROM
(   SELECT 
         sales.article_id,
         sum(sales.euro_value),
         sum(sales.qty)
    from SALES_TABLE sales
    where year >= 2011
    group by article_id
) sales
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(   SELECT 
         promo.article_id,
         sum(promo.euro_value),
         sum(promo.qty)
    from PROMOTION_TABLE promo
    where year >= 2011
    group by article_id
) promo

ON sales.article_id = promo.article_id

GROUP BY sales.article_id;
```

Some notes on the query:

1. Both the inner queries return huge number of rows due to large number of articles. Running explain on teradata, the inner queries themselves take very less time, but the join takes a long time.
2. Assume primary key on article_id is present and both the tables are partitioned by year.
3. Left Outer Join because second table contains optional data.

So, can you suggest a better way of writing this query.  Thanks for reading this far :)

Comment: What is the PRIMARY INDEX of the PROMO and SALES tables? It sounds like a spool redistribution or skew problem may be affecting your query. Can you share the EXPLAIN as well?

Comment: Both of your inner queries produce unique `article_id` values, because the corresponding results are grouped by `article_id`. Therefore, you don't need to group by `article_id` in your outer query. Try getting rid of the outer grouping and see if that speeds up your query in any way.

Comment: yes I agree. In this query, an outer group by is not necessary. but in terms of performance, it didn't make much of a difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really sure how the avg function got into the mix, so I'm removing it.

```
SELECT article_id,
       (SUM(sales_value) - SUM(promo_value)) /
       (SUM(sales_qty) - SUM(promo_qty))
FROM (
    SELECT 
         article_id,
         sum(euro_value) AS sales_value,
         sum(qty) AS sales_qty,
         0 AS promo_value,
         0 AS promo_qty
    from SALES_TABLE sales
    where year >= 2011
    group by article_id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
         article_id,
         0 AS sales_value,
         0 AS sales_qty,
         sum(euro_value) AS promo_value,
         sum(qty) AS promo_qty
    from SALES_TABLE sales
    where year >= 2011
    group by article_id
) AS comb

GROUP BY article_id;
```